# Meta property og:image not working in whatsapp

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am Working On sharing my website URL in different social medias. In skipe its working perfectly but whats app its not working. I added different code for both. Please check my code. Both I used in same page. Is this right?. Please Guide me Correctly
For Other I used this code

```
<meta property="og:image" content="Images/SharingLogo.png" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="628" />
```

For  Whats App

```
<meta property="og:image" content="Images/SharingLogoWhatsup.png" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="300" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="200" />
```

Comment: I think you need also og:title , og:type ,og:url and maybe og:description. just check documentation https://opengraphcheck.com/

Comment: already added og:title, og:type

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: the link to the image needs to be the full website URL, not local.